# Recommendation wanted for Neuronal Network Type and Topology

Tags: neural-network

I have a study project in microcontroller applications. There is a board with a 2 x 2 magnetic sensors and a magnet. The purpose is to compute the position (X, Y, Z) of the magnet by using the data of the 4 sensors (far left, far right, near left, near right). A sensor have an output of 0..5 volts (without a magnetic field the output is 2.5 volt).

[image: Hardware with 2 x 2 magnetic sensors and a magnet]

Now I want train a neuronal network to predict from the 4 sensor inputs the x, y, z coordinates of the magnet. But I don't have an idea of the correct neuronal network type (Multilayer Perceptron, Adaline, Hopfield and all the others) to use and the topology (how many layers and how many hidden neurons per layer).

Last week I took a measurement by using Lego building blocks to get an "exact" position of the magnet and saved the sensor data. You can find the measurement here:[measurement03_xyz.csv](http://vertex.dreamfall.at/temp/measurement03_xyz.csv). Here is an excerpt of the measurement at height/z = 10.6 mm

```
Lt.Far  Rt.Far  Lt.Near Rt.Near X   Y   Z
2.45357 2.43891 2.43891 2.52688 -16 -16 10.6
2.45846 2.46334 2.51222 2.6784  -8  -16 10.6
2.48289 2.46334 2.63441 2.68328 0   -16 10.6
2.49267 2.45357 2.69306 2.54643 8   -16 10.6
2.46334 2.43402 2.56598 2.48778 16  -16 10.6
2.46334 2.51222 2.46823 2.65396 -16 -8  10.6
2.51711 2.64907 2.62463 3.14272 -8  -8  10.6
2.69306 2.72239 3.15738 3.38221 0   -8  10.6
2.74194 2.56598 3.41642 2.84457 8   -8  10.6
2.58065 2.45846 2.77615 2.53666 16  -8  10.6
2.48289 2.62952 2.46823 2.69795 -16 0   10.6
2.66862 3.18671 2.66373 3.33822 -8  0   10.6
3.24536 3.4262  3.33822 3.57282 0   0   10.6
3.46041 2.83969 3.63148 2.90323 8   0   10.6
2.81525 2.51222 2.90811 2.54643 16  0   10.6
2.49267 2.65885 2.45357 2.57576 -16 8   10.6
2.69306 3.26979 2.54154 2.81036 -8  8   10.6
3.37732 3.57282 2.81525 2.93255 0   8   10.6
3.5826  2.88368 2.88368 2.65396 8   8   10.6
2.8739  2.51711 2.6393  2.49756 16  8   10.6
2.47312 2.55621 2.42913 2.50244 -16 16  10.6
2.56598 2.76637 2.46334 2.54154 -8  16  10.6
2.81036 2.84946 2.50733 2.55621 0   16  10.6
2.87879 2.63441 2.52199 2.51711 8   16  10.6
2.64907 2.47801 2.48778 2.47312 16  16  10.6
```

(first 4 columns are the sensor inputs in volts and the last 3 columns are the position in mm)

My first attempt was with [Neurophstudio](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/) to create a Multilayer Perceptron network like this:
[image: 3 Perceptron Network with 3 hidden layers]

But when I begin with the training, the total network error goes very, very, very slowly down.

I hope that someone with experience in neuronal networks can give me an advice which network type and topology too choose.

**In Addition**: Here some graphs of the measurement:

-Voltage of the left, near sensor in volts:

[image: Voltage of the left, near sensor in volts]

-Voltage of the left, near sensor in volts in dependence of the distance to the fix point (X=-8mm, Y=0mm, Z=1mm) for all measurered points (left) and for only the points on the XZ-Plane at y=0mm:

[image: Voltage of the left, near sensor in volts in dependence of the distance to the fix point (X=-8mm, Y=0mm, Z=1mm)]

Comment: Just a quick note: Hopfield is used to make a generative model (ie: the input is a noisy digit and you want to "fix" it so that it's closer to the archetype of this digit)  and cannot be used alone to classify or predict usually ; Perceptrons and Adalines are very very old models of feed-forward neural networks. You should look for a simple linear feed-forward multi-layer neural network, and if that doesn't work, you can just switch it to logistic regression instead of linear regression. See Week 2 and Week 6 lectures of the Machine Learning course on Coursera by Andrew Ng.

Answer (score 0):

An MLP should do. Make it as simple as you possibly can (but no simpler). Try only one hidden layer first, with as few neurons as possible, e.g. start with 4-5-3 (single hidden layer with 5 neurons). Train and validate the network, and only add more layers or neurons as long as they provide value.

Remember to separate your training set into training and validation sets or you will risk overfitting the data, especially if you choose a complex network. As long as you get lower errors in validation you can increase complexity. If you start seeing lower errors on the training set but no difference/higher errors on unseen data, you are overfitting and should go back to a simpler network.

Also consider normalizing your data as it helps training, e.g. invent a coordinate system and voltage reference system where both inputs and outputs are scaled to help the training algorithm converge. [Here is a good article on normalization and encoding](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/07/01/neural-network-data-normalization-and-encoding.aspx)

Comment: Thank you! First I normalized the data as described in the article, i.e. substract the sensor data by the there mean and divided by there standard deviation. The x/y/z data gets untouched. Now I switched from Neurophstudio to its framework Neuroph, so I can programatically change the topology much faster. I've tested one layer with 3, 4, 5...9 neurons, two layers with increasing neuron count and decreasing count and different activation functions (Sigmoid, Tanh, Sin, etc.) but without any results. Either the net error is alternating or decreasing very, very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't like it when people answer questions like: "how to use X to solve Z" with something like "why use X when you could use Y" so I apologize in advance for doing just that.

In your case, I would just triangulate the position of the magnet from the values of the 4 sensors in 4 groups of 3 with no need to train a neural network.

If you have your sensors labeled like this:

```
A o ---------------o B
  |\             / |
  |  \         /   |
  |    \     /     |
  |      \ /       |
  |      / \       |
  |    /     \     |
  |  /         \   |
  |/             \ |
D o ---------------o C
```

Then you have the following 4 groups to use (A,B,C) (A,D,C) (D,A,B) and (B,C,D). And finding the X,Y,Z coordinates of the magnet reduces to solving the prism which is a geometric problem.

That said, if you are intent on using a neural network for the task you'll have to experiment with different configurations until you're happy with the results.

- Make sure you have a really large training set.
- Then create a separate cross-validation data set

The idea is to use the training set to train the network and the cross validation set to explore the effects of changing various parameters such as the topography of the neural network or learning coefficients etc.

Comment: Thank you for the idea to use triangulating instance of a neuronal network. I've added 2 graphs that shows the dependence of the voltage to the distance of the left, near sensor (in your figure D). All the other sensor data have similar graphs. So I think it is impossible to find a function `f: sensor_data -> distance`. The Training set is big enough. It consists of 5 x 5 x 9 = 225 samples.

Comment: @Vertex - I'm not an expert but I would say 200 samples is considered a small data set. Try with 2000 or 5000 points. There's a point beyond which adding more data won't add any value but I'd venture to guess you're far from reaching that with 200 samples.  Regarding the triangulation idea - I don't know what to say, it's all speculation - but it should work..

Comment: ok, maybe you're right that I need more samples than only 225. The problem is, that the sensors can only detect the magnet in few cm distance. The Lego pimpels/nobs have a distance of 8 mm. Maybe it would work with millimeter paper where I phase the magnet.